Trouble in normalising two pairs of vectors
In the following code, I have two pairs of vector u0,u1 and v0,v1. These depend on parameters $a>0,b>0,c>0$ and importantly $c>b$. The overlap $u_0^\dagger \cdot v_0$ and $u_1^\dagger \cdot v_1$ is not equal to 1.
Now, I define new vectors $u_{0new} = u_{0}/\sqrt{u_0^\dagger v_0}$, $v_{0new} = v_{0}/\sqrt{u_0^\dagger v_0}$ and $u_{1new} = u_{1}/\sqrt{u_1^\dagger v_1}$, $v_{1new} = v_{1}/\sqrt{u_1^\dagger v_1}$.
 $Assumptions = a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && t > 0 && c > b
        (*Definition of vectors*)       
u0 = {-((I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/(c*
        Sqrt[1 + Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/c]^2])), 
   1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/c]^2]};
u1 = {-((I*b - Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/(c*
        Sqrt[1 + Abs[(I*b - Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/c]^2])), 
   1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[(I*b - Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/c]^2]};
v0 = {-(((-I)*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/(c*
        Sqrt[1 + Abs[((-I)*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/c]^2])), 
   1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[((-I)*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/c]^2]};
v1 = {-(((-I)*b - Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/(c*
        Sqrt[1 + Abs[((-I)*b - Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/c]^2])), 
   1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[((-I)*b - Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/c]^2]};
            
(*Overlap of vectors*) 
 FullSimplify[ConjugateTranspose[u0] . v0]
 FullSimplify[ConjugateTranspose[u1] . v1]
            
(*Here I define c0 and c1 square-root of the overlap of u0,v0 
and u1,v1 and divide with it the respective vectors*)
c0 = Sqrt[(-b^2 + c^2 - I*b*Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/c^2]; 
c1 = Sqrt[(-b^2 + c^2 + I*b*Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/c^2]; 
u0new = u0/c0; 
v0new = v0/c0; 
u1new = u1/c1; 
v1new = v1/c1; 
(*Now I expect the new vectors to be normalised to 1*)
FullSimplify[ConjugateTranspose[u0new] . v0new]
FullSimplify[ConjugateTranspose[u1new] . v1new]

Clearly $u_{0new}^\dagger \cdot v_{0new}$ and  $u_{1new}^\dagger \cdot v_{1new}$ should be now equal to 1, but that is now what Mathematica gives me, instead I have
{{-Sign[b^2 - c^2 + I b Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2]]}}
{{Sign[-b^2 + c^2 + I b Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2]]}}

What am I missing here?

You're running into issue of taking square roots of complex numbers, and how the square root is multi-valued and so Mathematica has to decide to take the principal root of the square root. You basically have to be more careful in the normalization procedure. In addition, it seems as if perhaps you need to do something like u0/c0 and v0/Conjugate[c0] instead, but I'm not sure that will actually fix the problem without testing, since all of this depends on the parameters b and c as to what those square roots are going to spit out.

By the way, you can just define your vectors  as { element1 , element 2} instead of {{elem1}, {elem2}}. The code is then simpler for the inner products: Conjugate[u0].v0 rather than ConjugateTranspose[u0].v0.

But really, do you have to split the "normalization" into two parts? Why not just define u0new = u0, v0new = v0/(-b^2 + c^2 - I*b*Sqrt[-b^2 + c^2])/c^2, and so on? It's not as if you're taking the inner product of a vector with itself, so you can just attach the "normalization" to one of the two vectors.

Distinguishing these latex u and v is a nightmare.

Thanks @march, you are right, I could simply define u0new=u0 and v0new=v0/c0^2. But this issue of handling square-root has confronted me in the past as well, though in a different context. So I just thought may be I would get some more insights of handling such situation.

@phy_std Unfortunately, that's more of a math question than a Mathematica one, once you understand that when Mathematica takes the square root of a complex number, it always choose the root that has positive real part. This can be tricky to deal with when you have symbolic expressions involving square roots and complex numbers. I've also often run into this issue, but I always fix it by thinking about the math, rather than trying to brute force it in Mathematica.

Replace Abs in formulas for u0, u1, v0, v1 with Identity then the result is 1. Although Mathematica is not able to simplify it to 1 symbolically, numerical substitution for a, b, c confirms it is indeed 1.
So after definition of u0, u1, v0, v1 use this:
u0 = u0 /. Abs -> Identity;
u1 = u1 /. Abs -> Identity;
v0 = v0 /. Abs -> Identity;
v1 = v1 /. Abs -> Identity;

Then you can substitute say a->2, b->11, c->15 to see that the result is 1.
